# Problem To excess the data of zip file in jupyter notebook code

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to upload a folder in my jupyter notebook code. So i created a zip file which contained 520 VM dataset  in .csv extension. For each VM their was a separate file. I have done the extraction part but now i don't know how to read the data and divide it in dependent and independent variable.

```
files = zf.ZipFile("ml_data.zip", 'r')
files.extractall()
x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
```